# Product of perfect maps is perfect

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $X=\prod_{s\in S}X_s$ and $Y=\prod_{s\in S}Y_s$ have the product topology and $f_s:X_s\to Y_s$ are functions. If each $f_s$ is perfect then $f=\prod_{s\in S}f_s$ is perfect.

I already proved $f$ is continuous and the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$ are compact. But I haven't proved $f$ is closed yet.

In this answer [Finite Product of Closed Maps Need Not Be Closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102744/finite-product-of-closed-maps-need-not-be-closed), it is shown the product of closed maps need not be closed, so the compactness of the fibers must be important, but how? Say $A\subseteq X$ is closed. Which way do I need to follow to prove $f(A)$ is closed? I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quotations from “General Topology” by Ryszard Engelking.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]